# Is it possible for me to get products that are discounted via Amazon's API?

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

I want to search Amazon's product API for discounted products (30% off or more). Is there a simple way to do this via the API?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For certain search indexes, you can ask for minimum percentage off:

http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSECommerceService/2011-08-01/DG/USSearchIndexParamForItemsearch.html

For instance, if I'm searching for Toys, I can get the minimum percentage off with the following parameters:

{"SearchIndex": "Toys", "Service": "AWSECommerceService", "AWSAccessKeyId": "xxx", "Timestamp": "2011-12-26T05:41:20Z", "Version": "2009-11-02", "Keywords": "Halo", "AssociateTag": "xxx", "MinPercentageOff": 30, "Operation": "ItemSearch", "ResponseGroup": "Large"}

However, if I'm searching for video games, the "MinPercentageOff" parameter is ignored.  The documentation page I included above shows which of the search indices accept this parameter - note that if the index doesn't support it it's simply ignored (the search doesn't fail, it just doesn't honor that parameter).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can quite easily, I ran the API and put a break point and looked down into the attributes and found what your looking for...

For the percentage discount you can find it here:

```
item->Offers->offersField->offerListingField->percentageSaved
```

For the price of the item its talking about you can find it here:

```
item->Offers->offersField->offerListingField->Price->formattedPriceField
```

Comment: No - I want to **only** search where `percentageSaved` is greater than 50

Comment: Well you can use what I have said above to only bring back results where percentage saved is greater than 50%, just an extra step , you cant search explicity by percentage saved.